# C# Seleniıum Iweb elements css selector

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am checking email on a website with c# selenium, if you have an email and if there is no email, adding class

Html

```
<div class="i24fI">
 <span class="coreSpriteInputError gBp1f"></span>
</div>
```

Code

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32((mailCount.Text)); i++)
{
    string email = helper.RastgeleKelime();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.xxxxxxx.com/accounts/emailsignup/");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Name("emailOrPhone"));
    IWebElement Fullname = driver.FindElement(By.Name("fullName"));
    username.SendKeys("cccc@hotmail.com");
    Fullname.SendKeys("ssssss");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    IWebElement error = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.i24fI span.coreSpriteInputError"));
    if (error != null)
    {
        avMailList.Items.Add(email.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        mailList.Items.Add(email.ToString());
    }
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

I check as above but

```
IWebElement error = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.i24fI span.coreSpriteInputError"));
```

If it doesn't exist, it gives an error because it can't find the element in its control.

Comment: Try to use "FindElements" instead of "FindElement" it gives you an empty list instead of an exception.

Comment: how to use findElements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FindElements` to get a collection of `IWebElement` and check the value of the first element using `FirstOrDefault()` from `Linq`

```
using System.Linq

ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> errors = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.i24fI span.coreSpriteInputError"));
IWebElement error = errors.FirstOrDefault();
```

Now `error` will be `IWebElement` or `null`.